# Продление действие ключа на Google Maps Javascript Api

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps-api, карты, key

==============

Подскажите, пожалуйста, с 2012 года пользуюсь специальным программным обеспечением по управлению спутниковыми референцыми станциями (программа Пилот производства Trimble и GNSS Spider от корпорации Leica) и со вчерашнего дня (26.04.2018) начались проблемы с лицензированием работы с web-компонентом Google Maps Javascript Api. Данный компонент используется в WEB приложениях указанных выше программных средств (необходимы для регистрации пользователей и мониторинга за работой в реальном времени системы станций и т.п.) Проблема с лицензированием связана с необходимостью обновления API ключа ( так называемый ключ для карт Google) и прописывания его в конфигурационных настройках WEB-серверов. Я почитал условия использования такого ключа и увидел, что имеется стандартный план работы, который имеет ряд ограничений на частоту получения данных с лицензионного компонента в день/секунду (зависит от настроенных квот) и т.п. и превышение установленного лимита должно оплачиваться дополнительно (как я понял необходимо заранее настроить платежный аккакунт и перейти на платный тариф). Однако меня вполне устроит стандартный план использования ключа. Да, уточню еще, что все ПО было приобретено легальным путем через официальных диллеров на юридическое лицо (с 2016 года акционировалось в АО Ростехинвентаризация ФБТИ). В то же время в правилаз пользования ключем API я не нашел ограничений на его действие, но как показала практика данное ограничение составляет 1 день, что крайне неудобно для пользования промышленной системой, работа которой должна обеспечиваться в режиме 24/7 (например, в праздники возможность обновить что либо крайне затруднительна или невозможна). После обновления ключа API (или получения нового) есть небольшая временная задержка для его регистрации и применения.
С учетом вышесказанного прошу разъяснить есть ли какая-то возможность продлить срок действия API-ключа для стандартного тарифа на год (или хотя бы на квартал) средствами API console в составе обласчной платформы Google Cloude Platform?
Если такой возможности нет, то подскажите, имеется ли инструмент автоматизации обращения в службе Console Cloud (через javascript или иные vba-подобные языки) для написания задания по расписанию, которое бы запрашивало после предварительной регистрации в выбранном Google аккаунте обновление API ключа и далее вставляло его во все зависимые WEB службы (но это уже другая история), меня же интересует первая часть, т.е. непосредственно запрос на обновление и получение значения обновленного API ключа.

#### Прошу по мере возможности рассмотреть мое обращение и при наличии рекомендаций/разъяснений прокомментировать его.

Comment: это вы к кому ? P.S. сформируйте это в удобночитаемый вопрос, а то от этой стены текста клонит в сон немножко.

Comment: На сколько я знаю, срок действия `Apikey` точно не один день. Возможно, вы все же превышаете лимиты использования.

Comment: Ограничения точно не превышаю, т.к. сайт не имеет широкого распространения. Однако иногда данная фича бывает очень важна, особенно когда она не функционирует как положено.

Comment: Также заметил, часто бывает так, что если карта открыта в нескольких браузерах, то после очередного сбоя она открывается только в _первом_ из них, в то время как в остальных в консоли отладчика отображается ошибка невозможности загрузить скрипт с параметром ApiKey с сайта google.

Comment: Какие будут варианты возобновления стабильной работы гугл карт с использованием Api ключа? При этом до начала недели все работало как часы и никаких сбоев не наблюдалось можно сказать вообще.